# Date query between two dates in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel-8

I would like to display only dates between start_date and end_date (format is "d.m.Y").

Unfortunately this does not work, what is wrong here?

```
$infos = Info::select('*')
          ->where('start_date', '<=', date('d.m.Y'))
          ->where('end_date', '>=', date('d.m.Y'))
          ->get();
```

Comment: try `now()` instead of `date('d.m.Y')`. This will work if start_date and end_date is date or datetime fileds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would recommend using the MySQL TIMESTAMP or DATE field types rather than storing it as a slightly unusual format (d.m.Y). Also consider using Carbon.

Those would allow you to make your life somewhat easier :

```
$now = Carbon::now(); // Or whatever date you want to use as the start date.
$then = $now->clone()->addDays(10); // Or whatever you want to set the end date as
$infos = Info::whereDate('start_date', '>=', $now)->whereDate('end_date', '<=', $then)->get();
```